# Tooltips (or other action) in QFileDialog

Tags: qt, qfiledialog, qtwidgets

I want to have a Tooltip (or ideally, a QWidget) pop-up when **hovering over a file** in a `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` instance.
Is there a way to do this without subclassing the class?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you want the tooltip shown (or widget etc...) to be based on the file name being hovered?

Comment: Correct.  An example would be to display a widget that renders a preview of the file in a popup tooltip-like window when you hover over a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any approved/definitive way of doing this.  The following is a rather hacky way of achieving what (I think) you want but which makes certain assumptions regarding the widget hierarchy associated with a [`QFileDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html) instance.  Specifically, it relies on the assumption that the widget hierarchy subtended by a `QFileDialog` instance will contain one or more `QAbstractItemView` instances...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QAbstractItemView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QCursor>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QToolTip>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QFileDialog fd;

  /*
   * Further to the comments by @Parisa.H.R, we need to make sure we use a
   * non-native file dialog here otherwise there's no way to get the desired
   * behaviour.
   */
  fd.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

  /*
   * Search the widget hierarchy under the QFileDialog looking for instances of
   * QAbstractItemView or derived classes.
   */
  for (auto *v: fd.findChildren<QAbstractItemView *>()) {
    std::clog << "view = " << v << "(type=" << v->metaObject()->className()
              << ", name=\"" << v->objectName().toStdString() << "\")\n";

    /*
     * Connect the view's entered signal to a lambda which, for the time being,
     * simply displays a tooltip showing the name of the filesystem item.
     */
    QObject::connect(v, &QAbstractItemView::entered,
                     [](const QModelIndex &index)
                       {
                         QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
                       });

    /*
     * In order to receive the QAbstractItemView::entered signal mouse tracking
     * must be enabled for the view.
     */
    v->setMouseTracking(true);
  }
  fd.exec();
}
```

Comment: I test your code , but it doesn't show any tooltip.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R Which OS are you on?  Do you see any of the logged output such as `view = ...(type=...)` etc. at the console?  If not you might want to explicitly request a [non-native `QFileDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum).

Comment: My OS is ubuntu , My log message is just `Gtk-Message: 16:32:41.984: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.` this

Comment: your connect didn't call at all.

Comment: If you're seeing a `Gtk` related message then you're almost certainly using a native dialog -- not the `Qt` one.  Try `fd.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog)`.  The code shown works as expected for me (Suse Linux + QT5.15.2).

Comment: @Parisa.H.R Thanks for the feedback/comments.  I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Hacky indeed, but an interesting technique.  Thanks.